# jquery-bootgrid: display a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-bootgrid

I want to display large collection of forms. jquery-bootgrid is good to display large data in IE8 (the best I found) in a client-side way (I display a HTML table and apply bootgrid to it).

The problem is that it converts all my inputs to text. No way to preserve the inputs and the links ?

Comment: how you use bootgrid ? show code

Comment: Very simply: $('#mytable').bootgrid({
                'columnSelection': false,});

Comment: try use with formatters http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Documentation#formatters

Comment: From the formetter, you have access to two variables: column, row. Column gives meta information on the column, row holds the user data but the HTML is already striped (eg for a SELECT this is the concatenation of the OPTION values)